# Weather api for providing weather forecast based upon location

Tags: mean, weather-api

Can anyone provide me the links of weather APIs which will provide weather forecast based upon the longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check these ones :

- https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2
- http://www.openweathermap.com/API
- http://api.accuweather.com/developers/

Besides, you can use Google with the following keywords : "weather forecast api"

Comment: If you consider this question as answered and satisfactory, please click the greyed check mark on the left sidfe of your question ;)